# How do you create an enumerable object that evaluates on demand out of another enumerable object?

Tags: ruby, enumeration

Given I have code like the following, what do I need to do to make it work?

```rb
config = {} #options for faster csv
input_file = "foo.csv"

# can be in any class or module
def count_item_groups(items)
    results = Hash.new(0)
    (items || []).each do |current|
        results[current.to_s] += 1
    end
    results
end

row_value_iterator = FasterCSV.foreach(input_file, config) do |row|
  yield return row[1]
end

result = count_item_groups(row_value_iterator)
```

Versus code like this

```
def do_it_all
    results = Hash.new(0)
    FasterCSV.foreach(input_file, config) do |row|
        results[row[1].to_s] += 1
    end
    results
end
```

Result should be a hash with keys of the row[1] values. `yield return` doesn't exist in Ruby, but I'm sure that Ruby can handle this type of code.

Comment: What is the yield return row[1] supposed to do? and what is the c# tag for?

Comment: yes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx I want to stream the row values, 1 by 1, out of the created iterator (row_value_iterator) into the count_item_groups method.

Comment: count_item_groups is just going to call .each on the collection. I want to do this to separate the code that knows what column in the CSV file to pull out from the code that will do the grouping.

Comment: Why are you linking to the C# documentation on that language's yield statement in a question about ruby?

Comment: @Pete because I'm looking to learn how to use the C# idiom in a Ruby manor. Hopefully learning the Ruby way of doing a similar task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what I understand you are asking: "How can I transform a method like `FasterCSV.foreach` that works imperatively (by doing side-effects) to something functional (that yields values) so I can modularize my code".

Answer: In Ruby you can transform a *each* method to an *Enumerator* object with [Object#enum_for](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-enum_for). Now you could use your `count_item_groups` with the output of the `map`, but I'd suggest to use Facets' [Enumerable#frequency](http://rdoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/Enumerable#frequency-instance_method):

```
results = FasterCSV.enum_for(:foreach, "file.csv", {}).map do |row|
  row[1].to_s
end.frequency
#=> {"val1"=>3, "val2"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, I assumed that is related to chainable feature.

Instead of passing the object iterator to another iterator as parameter, in ruby you can chain these iterators. It mignt look like this.

```
row_value_iterator = FasterCSV.foreach(input_file, config).map do |row|
  row[1]
end

result = row_value_iterator.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |current,results|
  results[current.to_s] += 1
end
```

Or do it in truly chain style:

```
result = FasterCSV.foreach(input_file,config).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |row,results|
  results[row[1].to_s] += 1
end
```

Comment: I think what the OP wants is be able to separate the CSV-reading from the occurrences-counting (which is a sound thing to do).